# "DO UPDATE SET" not working as expected

Tags: sql, postgresql, unique, upsert, postgresql-9.5

I'm using the PDO library in PHP and I'm generating a PostgreSQL statement like this:

```sql
INSERT INTO production_work (order_id, producer_id, sw)
VALUES (?,?,?)
ON CONFLICT (order_id, producer_id, day)
DO UPDATE SET sw = EXCLUDED.sw + ?
RETURNING ident
```

and for the parameters to the PDO execute() statement I'm passing in the array `[7172, 10, 1, 1]`.

That production_work table has a default value for the `day` parameter of `now()` which is why I don't pass it in, and a unique constraint set on the three fields listed for the `ON CONFLICT` part.

When there is no conflict, it's correctly setting the `sw` column's value to 1.  However, when there is a conflict, and the value of that `sw` column is currently 0, then after this statement runs the `sw` column ends up with a value of 2, not 1.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The record `EXCLUDED` contains values which were to be inserted but caused the conflict, so `EXCLUDED.sw` = 1 in this case. There is no need to add to it another 1:

```sql
INSERT INTO production_work (order_id, producer_id, sw)
VALUES (?,?,?)
ON CONFLICT (order_id, producer_id, day)
DO UPDATE SET sw = EXCLUDED.sw
RETURNING ident;
```

If you want to add a given value to the existing one use:

```sql
INSERT INTO production_work (order_id, producer_id, sw)
VALUES (?,?,?)
ON CONFLICT (order_id, producer_id, day)
DO UPDATE SET sw = sw + EXCLUDED.sw
RETURNING ident;
```

Comment: Interesting. So I simplified my example. Along with sw I have about 10 more columns I'm using just like that one. Do I need to list them all out in the update part?

Comment: Yes, you should set all the columns you want to be updated.

Comment: Thanks!  I'll try this when I get back home tonight.

Comment: OK, this still isn't what I'm looking for.  Basically I'm passing in a value for `sw` and I want that added to any existing value of `sw` if that row already exists.  Doing the code you showed here isn't adding the value if there is already a value.  So if no row exists yet, it sets `sw` to the given value.  If the row does exist, then I want it to add that value to whatever already exists.

Comment: This works, thanks.  Just had to change the second 'sw' to 'production_work.sw'